# After adding my website to a new server, I keep getting a unexpected end of file error, but the file is identitcal to it's original source

Tags: php, javascript, errors, buddypress, server

I have this script that changes buddypress' cover image template. this file works fine on my server, but as soon as I moved it to my client's server, it broke. I keep getting the error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /var/www/vhosts/womenschapter.com/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/jupiterx-child/buddypress/members/single/cover-image-header.php on line 102
```

the file is identical across both sites though, and mine works perfectly. I can also add as many php closing tags as I want, but I still get the same error. I almost feel like the new server might be configured differently, but I am completely in the dark here.

This is my code:

```
  <?php
/**
 * BuddyPress - Users Cover Image Header
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 * @version 3.0.0
 */
?>

<div class="DMUserContent">

    <!-- New HTML -->
        <a class="DMImageColumn" href="<?php bp_displayed_user_link(); ?>">
            <?php bp_displayed_user_avatar( 'type=full' ); ?>
        </a>

        <div class="DMContentColumn">
            <h3>MEET</h3>
            <?php if ( bp_is_active( 'activity' ) && bp_activity_do_mentions() ) : ?>
                <h1>
                    <?php 
                    $DMName  = bp_profile_field_data( 'field=First Name', bp_displayed_user_id() );
                    ?> <?php
                    $DMName .= bp_profile_field_data( 'field=Last Name', bp_displayed_user_id() );
                    echo $DMName;
                    ?>
                </h1>
                <!-- <h5>@<?php // bp_displayed_user_mentionname(); ?></h5> -->
            <?php endif;
            ?>
            <h4><?php bp_profile_field_data( 'field=Job Title', bp_displayed_user_id() ); ?> - <?php bp_profile_field_data( 'field=Company Name', bp_displayed_user_id() ); ?></h4>
            <p class="DMSPshortDescription"><?php bp_profile_field_data( 'field=Short description of your services', bp_displayed_user_id() ); ?></p>
            <div class="Divider"></div>
            <p class="DMSPWebLink"><?php echo bp_profile_field_data( 'field=Website', bp_displayed_user_id()); ?></p>
            <div class="DMSPSocialMediaLinks">
                <?php
                if (bp_get_profile_field_data( 'field=Instagram name', bp_displayed_user_id()) != null && bp_get_profile_field_data( 'field=Instagram name', bp_displayed_user_id()) != "" ){ ?>
                    <a class="DMSPinstagram"  href='https://instagram.com/<?php echo bp_profile_field_data( 'field=Instagram name', bp_displayed_user_id()); ?>'>

                        <?php echo bp_profile_field_data( 'field=Instagram name', bp_displayed_user_id()); ?></a>
                <?php
                } ?>

                <?php
                if (bp_get_profile_field_data( 'field=Facebook name', bp_displayed_user_id()) != null && bp_get_profile_field_data( 'field=Facebook name', bp_displayed_user_id()) != "" ){ ?>
                    <a class="DMSPfacebook" href='https://facebook.com/<?php echo bp_profile_field_data( 'field=Facebook name', bp_displayed_user_id()); ?>'>

                        <?php echo bp_profile_field_data( 'field=Facebook name', bp_displayed_user_id()); ?></a>
                <?php
                } ?>

                <?php
                if (bp_get_profile_field_data( 'field=Twitter name', bp_displayed_user_id()) != null && bp_get_profile_field_data( 'field=Twitter name', bp_displayed_user_id()) != "" ){
                    ?>
                    <a class="DMSPtwitter" href='https://Twitter.com/<?php echo bp_profile_field_data( 'field=Twitter name', bp_displayed_user_id()); ?>'>

                        <?php echo bp_profile_field_data( 'field=Twitter name', bp_displayed_user_id()); ?></a>
                <?php
                } ?>


                <?php
                if (bp_get_profile_field_data( 'field=Email', bp_displayed_user_id()) != null && bp_get_profile_field_data( 'field=Email', bp_displayed_user_id()) != "" ){
                    ?>
                    <a class="DMSPemail" href='mailto:<?php echo bp_profile_field_data( 'field=Email', bp_displayed_user_id()); ?>'>

                        <?php echo bp_profile_field_data( 'field=Email', bp_displayed_user_id()); ?></a>
                <?php
                } ?>
            </div>
            <?php
            if ( bp_is_my_profile() ){
                ?> <a href="<?php bp_displayed_user_link()?>profile" class='WCStyleButton'>Edit Profile</a>



                <?php }
            ?>
            <div id="item-header-content">

                    <?php
                    bp_nouveau_member_header_buttons(
                        array(
                            'container'         => 'ul',
                            'button_element'    => 'button',
                            'container_classes' => array( 'member-header-actions' ),
                        )
                    );
                    ?>

                    <?php bp_nouveau_member_hook( 'before', 'header_meta' ); ?>



            </div>
        </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Please properly format your code (in the question), and not sure if this solves the problem, but there's an unwanted/unexpected (or uncommented) `----------` in your code.

Comment: I'll fix it now

Comment: @SallyCJ I can't find the lines you mentioned, I think it's only in stackexchange

Comment: Ok, you've got this - `<?php; }` - in your code. Just change that to `<?php }`.

Comment: @SallyCJ I removed it, but it didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant to say "try to change"... And if the issue is still there, try to change all the `}?>` to `} ?>` (i.e. put a space before the `?`). If that still doesn't work, then one of [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11482527) might help.

Comment: And also the `{?>` (change that to `{ ?>`) and `)?>` (change that to `) ?>`) - i.e. once again, add a space (or a new line, whichever is better..) before the `?>` (and after the `<?php`).

Comment: Another general trick for this kind of thing is to just re-upload the files.

Comment: I'll try all of these in a bit

Comment: @SallyCJ it worked. I could kiss you, you don't even realize how much pressure I've been under. add your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue has already been resolved via the comments and the current state of the question already includes the corrected code. But I thought I should post this answer as a reminder for you, me and everyone reading this. :)

So first off, here's a helpful excerpt from [an article on WP Engine](https://wpengine.com/support/resolving-unexpected-end-of-file-errors/):

> The “unexpected end of file” error is not specific to WordPress, and
>   *can happen on any PHP-based website*. This specific error means the file mentioned in the error message ends abruptly without the *proper
>   closing tags*, and the code was unable to be parsed as a result.

And now here's the comment which helped solved the problem:

> And also the `{?>` (change that to `{ ?>`) and `)?>` (change that to
>   `) ?>`) - i.e. once again, add a space (or a new line, whichever is
>   better..) before the `?>` (and after the `<?php`).

And based on [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11482620), I believe the problem was the `{?>` which should have been written as `{ ?>` (i.e. an opening bracket *followed by a space* then the closing PHP tag).

So in summary, ***you should not put brackets directly close to the opening/closing PHP tag, but separate it with a space***:

```php
// Bad
{?>
<?php}

// Good
{ ?>
<?php }
```

However, regarding this: "*the file is identical across both sites though, and mine works perfectly*"; it's probably because some PHP installations/setups are forgiving to brackets that are directly close to the opening/closing PHP tag. Because that seemed to be the case with my first test which was on a PHP 7.3 (Windows) install, except that I had to change the `<?php; }` to `<?php }`, but that's probably just a typo in the question.. :)